# How to gain greater control of network packets on Android

Tags: java, android, tcp, network-programming, packets

I'm looking to design an application that will require some deep control over IP packets. Looking over the reference guide on the developers site at Android I see very limited control over packets from java.net:SocketOptions and java.net:DatagramPacket. Specifically I'm looking to control the individual bits within the packet to set TCP Flags, SYN/ACK/RST, and so forth. Based on the docs I am assuming I cannot do this within the Java API provided by Android and I'm guessing I'll have to do it some other way?

Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Maybe you can do this using the NDK, but I have no experience using it, so I can't even tell you whether the NDK supplies us with (Berkeley) sockets.

Comment: Another question here is if this is possible without rooting? Usually raw packets requires root privs on most operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears the SDK cannot do as I had needed. The NDK may be able to but on further thought I believe even using that will require root privs to construct raw packets. As I have no intent to root my phone at this time, this will all be put on hold.